# Can you explain the intuition of Tom Apostol's proof of the Additive Property of sets?

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, supremum-and-infimum

In his book Calculus Vol. 1, Apostol writes the following proof:

> Theorem I.32. Let $h$ be a given positive integer and let $S$ be a set of real numbers.
>
> (a) *If $S$ has a supremum, then for some $x$ in $S$ we have*$$x > \sup S - h$$
>
> Theorem I.33 Additive Property: *Given nonempty subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb R$, let $C$ denote the set*$$C = \left\{a + b \mid a \in A, b \in B\right\}.$$
>
> (a) *If each of $A$ and $B$ has a supremum, then $C$ has a supremum, and* $$\sup C  = \sup A + \sup B.$$
>
> *Proof.* Assume each of $A$ and $B$ has a supremum. If $c \in C$, then $c = a+b$, where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. Therefore, $c \le \sup A +\sup B$; so $\sup A + \sup B$ is an upper bound for $C$. This shows that $C$ has a supremum and that $$\sup C \le \sup A + \sup B.$$
>
> Now let $n$ be any positive integer. By Theorem I.32 (with $h = \frac{1}{n}$) there is an $a$ in $A$ and a $b$ in $B$ such that $$a > \sup A - \frac1n, \quad b > \sup B - \frac1n.$$
>
> Adding those inequalities, we obtain $$a + b > \sup A + \sup B - \frac2n, \quad or \quad \sup A + \sup B < a + b + \frac2n \le \sup C + \frac2n,$$
>
> since $a + b \le \sup C$. Therefore we have shown that $$\sup C \le \sup A + \sup B < \sup C + \frac2n$$
>
> for every integer $n \ge 1$. By Theorem I.31, we must have $\sup C = \sup A + \sup B.$ This proves (a).

Theorem I.31 is Theorem 1.2 on the question I asked here:

[Is my proof of "Theorem 1.2" correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2813928/is-my-proof-of-theorem-1-2-correct)

My problem is, I don't understand the steps from adding the inequalities and onwards. Any insight you could provide would be most helpful.

Comment: Do you know what "adding the inequalities" means?  Most of these steps are just very simple algebra.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes. I understand how they are added, I just get stuck when amending the $\sup C$, and figuring out whether the sign should be inclusive or exclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the inequalities we have $$a+b> \sup A + \sup B - \frac2n.$$

Adding $\frac{2}{n}$ to both sides and flipping the inequality around gives $$\sup A + \sup B < a + b + \frac2n.$$  But $a+b\leq\sup C$, so $$a+b+\frac{2}{n}\leq \sup C+\frac{2}{n}.$$  Combining the last two inequalities we conclude that $$\sup A + \sup B < \sup C+\frac{2}{n}.$$
Since it was shown earlier in the proof that $\sup C \le \sup A + \sup B$, we thus have $$\sup C \le \sup A + \sup B < \sup C + \frac2n.$$  Moreover, $n$ here can be any positive integer.  So, Theorem I.31 with $y=2$ tells us that $\sup A+\sup B=\sup C$.

Comment: Thank you. As one quick question, how do you know that $a + b \le \sup C$?

Comment: $a+b$ is an element of $C$.

Comment: I can't believe I never thought of that. It all makes sense now. Because your answer has been so helpful, do you have any advice on the intuitive understanding of proofs? I ask because I understand why Apostol's proof is true, but I know that, from scratch, I would not have been able to formulate it myself. I can prove the case for the infimum, but only using the supremum proof as a blueprint.

Comment: When you read proofs like this, I would recommend thinking about what they _mean_ and trying not to get lost in the algebra.  For instance, in this proof, $\frac{1}{n}$ is not actually important--it's just some small number (that can be arbitrarily small).  So, the idea is, you pick $a$ and $b$ that are really close to $\sup A$ and $\sup B$.  Then, $a+b$ will be really close to $\sup A+\sup B$.  But $a+b\in C$, so this shows $\sup C$ can't be very much smaller than $\sup A+\sup B$.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for next time. I'm 16 years old, and I'm attempting to self-study Calculus in a rigorous, proof-based manner. I don't want to learn from a general high school curriculum because I don't think that would be challenging enough. I believe that math is beautiful, elegant, and poetic, which is only fed by rigorous texts like that of Apostol's, the quality of which a high school course could never top. Thank you for your answer and advice, it has been most helpful to my endeavors to self-study of mathematics.

Comment: @JamieCorkhill I upvoted because I think your question is excellent.  I really like Apostol's book.  I recommend that you **go slow and careful**: each time that you are **not sure of the validity** of one of Apostol's proofs, **do just what you did**: post it here, showing the work that you did trying to verify the proof.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you. I've never seen an author treat the real number system as Apostol does, going even so far as to display the meaning of the <, >, etc., symbols in a rigorous manner. The fact that it's so proof based makes it much harder, and there are times when I've thought I would learn faster from an average Calculus book. But then I take a step back and realize, despite its difficulty, just how powerful that really is, and how profoundly it provides one with the insight for what it must have been like for people like Euler and Archimedes at the forefront of mathematics in their time