# Confusion on Additive Property of Supremum and Infimum - Theorem I.33 Apostol Calculus I

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, proof-explanation, supremum-and-infimum

There is a great question and answer to the first part of Theorem I.33 of Apostol Calculus "Additive Property" [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814076/can-you-explain-the-intuition-of-tom-apostols-proof-of-the-additive-property-of). I'm hoping someone can verify my attempt at part (b).

Apostol provides the following theorems

> **Theorem I.30:** *If $x > 0$ and if $y$ is an arbitrary real number, there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $nx > y$
>
> **Theorem I.31:** *If three real numbers a, x and y satisfy the inequalities* $$ a \leq x \leq a + y/n$$ *for every integer $n \geq 1$ then $x = a$.
>
> **Theorem I.32:** Let $h$ be a given positive integer and let $S$ be a set of real numbers.
>
> (a) *If $S$ has a supremum, then for some $x$ in $S$ we have*$$x > \sup S - h$$
>
> (b) *If S has an infimum, then for some $x \text{ in } S$ we have* $$x < \inf S + h$$
>
> **Theorem I.33 Additive Property:** *Given nonempty subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb R$, let $C$ denote the set*$$C = \left\{a + b \mid a \in A, b \in B\right\}.$$
>
> (a) *If each of $A$ and $B$ has a supremum, then $C$ has a supremum, and* $$\sup C  = \sup A + \sup B.$$
>
> (b) *If each of $A$ and $B$ has an infimum, then $C$ has an infimum, and* $$\inf C  = \inf A + \inf B.$$

*Proof of (b)*

(1) Assume each of $A$ and $B$ has an infimum.

(2) If $c \in C$, then $c = a+b$, where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.

(3) $\forall a \in A, a \ge inf A$, $\forall b \in B, b \ge inf B$ (definition of infimum)

(4) $a + b \ge \inf A + \inf B$, (thm I.25)

(5) $c \ge \inf A +\inf B$ (replacement)

(6) $\inf C \ge \inf A + \inf B.$ ( from (5) and definition of inf)

(7) Let n be any positive integer. $a < \inf A + \frac1n$ and $b < \inf B + \frac1n$ (thm 1.32 with 1/n as h)

(8) $a + b \lt \inf A + \inf B + \frac2n$ (add inequalities, thm I.25)

(9) $a + b - \frac2n \lt \inf A + \inf B$ (thm I.16)

(10) $\inf C - \frac2n \leq a + b - \frac2n$ (definition of inf and thm I.16)

(11) $\inf C - \frac2n \lt \inf A + \inf B \leq \inf C$ (putting inequalities together)

At this point, the meaning seems right - however we can't use Theorem I.31 in it's current form. So I need to show Theorem I.31 can also be written as $$ a - \frac{y}{n} \leq x \leq a$$

**Assume x = a** 
done

**Assume x < a.**

(1) $(a - x) \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$

(2) $n(a - x) \gt y$ (from thm I.30)

(3) $n(x - a) \lt -y$ (field and order theorems)

This is a contradiction, so $x > a$ cannot hold and $x = a$.

Finally, by Theorem I.31 (reworded) $\inf C = \inf A + \inf B$

Let me know what you think, this feels correct but I wonder if the reworking of Theorem I.31 is necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a bunch of quantifiers. For example, in your statement (7), what are $a$ and $b$? Is it for **all** $a$ and $b$? Are they elements of $C$, $A$, $B$, or what?

Of course, I assume you mean that

> "There **exist** elements $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that the inequalities hold."

However you need to make this clear! For example, in inequality (11), what is the quantifier for $n$? Is it a "for all" or a "there exists"?

If we wrote the quantifiers, it should be

(11) For all positive integers $n$, $\inf C-2/n\leq \inf A+\inf B\leq\inf C$.

In particular, if $n$ is any positive integer, then $2n$ is also a positive integer, and we can apply (11) to $2n$ instead and obtain

(11)' For all positive integers $n$, $\inf C-1/n\leq\inf A+\inf B\leq\inf C$.

Which is what you want.

The same type of argument holds for your "modification of Theorem I.31". What is $y$?!

---

Second, you need to argue **why** $C$ has an infimum before being able to write $\inf C$ anywhere.

---

As a last comment, tt seems you want to write a proof in the sense of deductive logic, but this should not be your approach, specially to calculus. Even if you look at Apostol's proofs that is not what he does. Of course, enumerating all your statements could make self-reference easier, however you need to put all quantifiers *everywhere*, which is time consuming.

---

Here's a way to write your proof in more standard terms (in a somewhat pedantic way, but this is not a problem: being precise is always better):

> Assume that each of $A$ and $B$ has an infimum. In order to prove that $C$ has an infimum, we need to prove that it has a lower bound.
>
> Let $c\in C$ [be arbitrary]. Then $c$ may be written as $c=a+b$, where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Then $\inf A\leq a$ and $\inf B\leq b$, so we may add these inequalities to obtain
>   $$c=a+b\geq\inf(A)+\inf(B)\tag{1}$$
>   Therefore, $\inf(A)+\inf (B)$  is a lower bound of $C$, and thus $C$ has an infimum. Moreover, equation (1) holds for all $c\in C$, and therefore 
>   $$\inf(A)+\inf(B)\leq\inf(C)\tag{2}.$$
>   Let us prove the converse inequality, and for this we will use Theorem I.31.
>
> Let $n$ be a positive integer. By Theorem I.32(b), there exist $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that
>   $$a-1/n\leq\inf(A)\leq a\qquad\text{and}\qquad b-1/n\leq\inf(B)\leq b.\tag{3}$$
>   Let $c=a+b$, which is an element of $C$ and in particular $\inf C\leq c$. Then adding the two inequalities in (3) yields
>   $$\inf(C)-2/n\leq c-2/n\leq\inf(A)+\inf(B).\tag{4}$$
>   Adding $2/n$ on the first and last term of (4) gives is $\inf (C)\leq\inf(A)+\inf(B)+2/n$, for any positive integer $n$. Using this with (2) yields
>   $$\inf(A)+\inf(B)\leq\inf(C)\leq(\inf(A)+\inf(B))+2/n\quad\text{ for any positive integer }n.$$
>   These are precisely the inequalities of Theorem I.31 (using $a=\inf(A)+\inf(B)$, $x=\inf(C)$ and $y=2$), which allows us to conclude that $\inf(A)+\inf(B)=\inf(C)$. *Q.E.D*

Comment: In the line above equation 4, it appears you meant to write $\inf(C) - \color{red}{2/n} \leq c - 2/n$.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response! I see where I'm muddling the proof by attempting to enumerate every theorem/axiom - your comment regarding the "standard way" is quite helpful in pulling me out of the weeds where it is not necessary. Regarding the application of Thm I.31 to the last part of your proof, is my reworking of Theorem I.31 to the form $a - \frac{y}{n} \leq x \leq a$ valid? Or are you applying it in a different way?

Comment: @jakekirsch I think I'm applying it the same way as you are, although I should say I don't really understand your proof and in particular what is the contradiction you get in there.

Comment: @JakeKirsch actually I just noticed that Theorem I.31 is already stated with the number "$y$", so there is really no need to that last argument using $k$ (simply use $y=2$. So yes, this is a sort of "dual" version to Theorem I.31 "if three real numbers $a$, $x$ and $y$, where $y>0$, satisfy $a-y/n\leq x\leq a$ for all positive integers $n$, then $a=x$". You can in fact obtain this version as a consequence of I.31, by "multiplying all inequalities by $-1$".

Comment: ah I see that now, I was following the form that Apostol uses to prove Theorem I.31 (granted mine is messy and incomplete) but the crux of it is that the contradiction comes when you apply Theorem I.30 to the statement $a - x > 0$. The result $n(x-a) \lt - y$ contradicts the inequality $a - \frac{y}{n} \leq x$

Comment: @JakeKirsch I understand now. Your ideas seem ok, it just a matter of solving more and more exercises ;). I edited my answer to use Theorem I.31 correctly and directly, too.

Comment: @Questioner agreed, your approach is much cleaner. This is actually the form I was trying to get to but didn't see that $\inf A + \inf B \leq \inf C \leq \inf A + \inf B + \frac{2}{n}$, would work - I was getting hung up on trying to get to $\inf C \leq \inf A + \inf B \leq \inf C + \frac{2}{n}$ because of how part a (linked question) was proved. Great answer and thanks for the help!